# How to make a histogram based on the second column of a large matrix and then calculate the sum efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

The matrix is like 4000 columns x 1e8 lines. Now I need to divide the 1e8 lines into 1000 bins based on the 2nd column and sum the lines in every bin. Finally, I would get 4000 columns x 1000 lines.

```
aa=np.random.rand(10000000, 4000)
l,r=min(aa[:,1]),max(aa[:,1])
bins=np.linspace(l,r,1001)
for bn in range(1000):
      ll,rr=bins[bn],bins[bn+1]
      np.sum(dd[(aa[:,1]>ll) &( aa[:,1]< rr) ],axis=0)' # one of the 1000 lines
```

I find the speed of the final step above is low.

Then I need to stack all the 1000 lines to generate the 1000 x 4000 matrix.

```
 @njit(parallel=True)
 def sumgood(bins, dd):
    results = np.zeros((1000, 4000), dtype=np.float64)
    for bn in range(1000):
      l, r = bins[bn], bins[bn+1]
      subset = dd[(dd[:,1] > l) & (dd[:,1] < r)] #column >l and column<r
      sum_subset = np.sum(subset, axis=0)
      results[bn] = sum_subset
    return results
 binmap=sumgood(bins, dd)
 ########################
 for bn in range(1000):
      l,r=bins[bn],bins[bn+1]
      exec(f'good{bn}=np.sum(dd[(dd[:,1]>l) &( dd[:,1]< r) ],axis=0)')
 binmap=np.concatenate([globals()[f'good{bn}'] for bn in range(1000)])
```

Comment: This part is confusing me: "based on the second column...". How does this column encode how the binning is done? Can it be swapped with the first column rather than (apparently) being sandwiched between columns to be summed (1 on the left, 3998 on the right)? What is the shape of the output (presumably an array with length equal to number of bins)? Example code with a smaller dataset would be helpful. I think I have a simple solution in mind, but i need to understand the bins to post an answer.

Comment: I think I understand now that *labels* (1000 distinct values) to bin by are in the second column of the array. So if this were a DataFrame, we would just `groupby` that column and sum the other columns, right?

Comment: The question has been modified.

Comment: Please ensure that the code is executable and produces the result you want. It has a syntax error, an undefined variable, and it appears to discard the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The updated problem appears to change in that we cannot calculate the row sums a priori, and the bin "labels" are not given as discrete values (rather they need to be calculated from the data).

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(83498345935)

# Generate data:
# 1e3 rows (instead of 1e8), 40 columns (instead of 4000), 10 bins (instead of 1000)
n_rows, n_cols, n_bins = 1000, 40, 10
x = rng.random((n_rows, n_cols))

# Compute bins from second column
bin_col = x[:, 1]
lb, ub = bin_col.min(), bin_col.max()
bin_width = (ub - lb) / n_bins
labels = (bin_col - lb) // bin_width
labels[labels == n_bins] = n_bins-1

# Compute sums
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=labels).groupby(level=0).sum()
df.shape  # (10, 40)
```

---

*Answer to original understanding of the problem*.

Consider a data array `x` in which the second column is labels to bin by and the remaining columns include values to be summed:

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
# 1e3 rows (instead of 1e8), 40 columns (instead of 4000)
x = rng.random((1000, 40))  
x[:, 1] = rng.integers(10, size=1000)  # 10 unique values (instead of 1000)
```

Isolate the bin labels in the second column, and calculate the sums of the remaining columns within each row. Determine bin labels and generate edges for the bins.

```
labels = x[:, 1]
rowsums = x[:, 0] + np.sum(x[:, 2:], axis=1)
bin_labels = np.arange(np.max(labels) + 1)
bin_edges = np.arange(-0.5, np.max(labels) + 1.5)
```

Use [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) to compute the binned sums. Compare against a looping reference implementation.

```py
from scipy import stats
res = stats.binned_statistic(labels, rowsums, statistic='sum', bins=bin_edges)
ref = [rowsums[labels==i].sum() for i in bin_labels]
np.testing.assert_allclose(res.statistic, ref)
```

Or using `pandas`, you don't need to generate the bin edges yourself:

```py
import pandas as pd
res2 = pd.Series(rowsums, labels).groupby(level=0).sum()
np.testing.assert_allclose(res2, ref)
```

If both of these are too slow or memory intensive, I can post pure-NumPy code, but these are simpler.

Comment: pandas would be faster. The data volume is too large.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the data volume is the actual challenge.

Your array size is about 300 GB, (10000000 * 4000 * 8) / 1024**3 = shape times float64 size in bytes (8 bytes) divided by bytes per GB.

I assume you do not have enough RAM to load the entire data set, so you should load the data in chunks.

In order to accelerate the number crunching, you could use Matt Haberland's solution, or use other methods such as numba, see example below.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit(parallel=True)
def linessum(lines, histcol, vmin, vmax, nbins, out):
    assert vmin <= vmax
    assert out.shape[0] == nbins
    for line in lines:
        value = line[histcol]
        if value == vmax:
            # max value corresponds to last bin
            idx = nbins - 1
        else:
            # calculate bin index
            idx = int(nbins * (value - vmin) / (vmax - vmin))
        # only take values within vmin vmax into account
        if idx >= 0 and idx < nbins:
            # note that numba takes care of this race condition
            out[idx, :] += line[:]

# simulate loading chunks of data
def create_chunk(start, length):
    arr = np.empty((length, ncols))
    arr[:, 0] = np.arange(start, start+length)
    arr[:, 1] = np.cos(arr[:, 0])
    arr[:, 2] = np.log1p(arr[:, 0])
    arr[:, 3] = np.sqrt(arr[:, 0] + 1)
    arr[:, 4:8] = 2*arr[:, :4]
    arr[:, 8:12] = arr[:, :4]**2 / nlines
    return arr

def chunkloader(chunksize):
    n, r = divmod(nlines, chunksize)
    for i in range(n):
        yield create_chunk(i*chunksize, chunksize)
    if r:
        yield create_chunk(i*chunksize, r)

# input array shape
nlines = 100000
ncols = 12

# set according to your RAM
chunksize = 10000

# histogram setup
nbins = 25

# something you can get from min max of the histogram column or set manually,
# see e.g. range parameter in numpy.histogram
cmin = -1
cmax = 1

# allocate and initialize memory for output
out = np.zeros((nbins, ncols))
# aggregate the chunks
for chunk in chunkloader(chunksize):
    linessum(chunk, 1, cmin, cmax, nbins, out)

print(out)
```

Note, that we can calculate the histogram index for each line individually. Making use of this allows to process the data in line chunks and it allows to reduce a lot the memory footprint of the application and makes the algorithm faster.

Another change is the use of reproducible data. Random numbers are good to mimic some input, but better use fake data that others can reproduce, so you are able to compare results.

Note further, your algorithm does not take the values at the bin edges into account.

Comment: njit does work for accelerating(code above ####), but compare with the for-loop (code below ####), why are their computation results inconsistent?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by inconsistent results?

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my njit code? binmap.shape are the same, but values in that two binmap are different

Comment: This might be a side effect of your parallelization. However, as noted in my answer, your algorithm does not take into account the histogram edges. BTW, how do you load your data array? Does it come from a file or from a database?

Comment: Keeping (parallel=True) or not does not change the result.  Reading dozens of data files and combining them would get dd (4000 columns x 1e8 lines).  This takes time, but shorter than the generation of the  matrix of the 4000 columns x 1000 lines.

Comment: Do you see a difference when you remove the jit decorator?

Comment: Note, that I would recommend a line by line algorithm as in my answer. You just need the histogram boundaries. Then you do not even need the parallel flag in numba, because you can create the output array for each chunk in parallel and at the end sum up. This is less error prone.